# Talk to MacOSX app from Chrome Extension

Tags: objective-c, macos, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension running in my browser. I also have a Mac OSX app I wrote in Swift/Objective-c in Xcode. I am wondering how this chrome extension can talk to the Mac OSX app on the same computer.

I am aware of the Chrome Extension API, but do not know how I can capture the information from that is sent by Chrome in Swift. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: See [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Ok, but this API doesn't tell me how I can talk from Swift, it only talks about sending the messages from the Chrome Extension, if I'm correct.

Comment: I knew about this API, but I wasn't sure how to do it in Swift or Objective-C. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @hockeybro Did you ever figure out this?

Answer (score 5):

There are two broad approaches you can take.

1. [Native Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). This does have the limitation that Chrome must launch the process (and communicate to it via STDIO) - you cannot attach to an existing process. The upside - the communication channel is pretty secure.
2. Your native app can expose a web server (or better yet, a WebSockets server) on a local port. The extension can then try to connect to this port and talk to your app. The downside is that anything (at least on the machine) can connect to your native app.

   This is a frequently used approach; for example, 1Password or various IDE integrations work this way.

You could combine the two approaches to launch the app with a "launcher" Native Host if it's not running.

Comment: If I wanted to do option 1, what would I need to configure on the Mac OSX native app side?

Comment: It should talk over STDIO conforming to Native Messaging protocol as defined in the docs.

Comment: @Xan @hockeybro Any luck finding how to get macos to see the messages via stdio? Ive tried many attempts using `FileHandle.standardInput` but no luck

Comment: @daidai Did you ever make it work ? I want to use the Native Messaging API but I can't find docs on how to do it from MacOS /Swift